# How can I reset my checkbox to be unchecked when modal box is closed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have created a modal box. Within my modal box there is text. The text is named publication and changes color between blue and red. The text changing color is linked to a checkbox being checked and unchecked.

I want the checkbox to be unchecked every time the modal box is opened and re-opened after being closed.

I have tried using `$('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',false);` but the checkbox is not always unchecked after the modal box is closed.

```html
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />

</head>

<style> 

.onlyThese{
cursor:pointer;
-webkit-user-select: none;  
-moz-user-select: none;     
-ms-user-select: none;      
 user-select: none;           
}




input[type="checkbox"]+label {  color:blue } 

input[type="checkbox"] { display: none }
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {  color:red } 
}

input:focus{
outline: none;   
}



</style>



<p> <a class="btn" href="#ex5">Sectors </a> </p>
    
<div id="ex5"; class="modal"; style="background-color:white">
    
<div style="float:left;">

<p> <input type="checkbox" id="group1" class="yourCheckbox" > <label for="group1" class="onlyThese">Publication </label> </p>

<div id="myDiv">the preparation and issuing of a book, journal, or piece of music for public sale.</div>
</div>





            
   
<div>
<p style="float:right"> 
<a href="#" rel="modal:close"; class="onlyThese;"> <b>Apply</b> </a> 
</p>    
</div>

</div>
 


<script>

  $('a[href="#ex5"]').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).modal({
    escapeClose: false,
    clickClose: false,
    showClose: false,
  });
});

$('.yourCheckbox').change(function(){
  if($(this).prop("checked")) {
$('#myDiv').show();
  } else {
$('#myDiv').hide();
  }
});

 $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',false);    
</script>
```

I expect:

- -the user to click on the modal box named sectors
- - the modal box to open and the text publication to be blue which is
    when it is unchecked
- -the user may choose to click apply which closes the modal box; but they can then open it again but the checkbox is now unchecked and the
  user has to then proceed to click on the text to check the checkbox
  again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the `$('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',false);` statement where you're initializing the modal each time:

```js
$('a[href="#ex5"]').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).modal({
    escapeClose: false,
    clickClose: false,
    showClose: false,
  });
  $('#myDiv').hide();
  $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
});

$('.yourCheckbox').change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    $('#myDiv').show();
  } else {
    $('#myDiv').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.onlyThese {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label {
  color: blue
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  color: red
}


}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery Modal -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
</head>
<p>
  <a class="btn" href="#ex5">Sectors </a>
</p>
<div id="ex5" ; class="modal" ; style="background-color:white">
  <div style="float:left;">
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" id="group1" class="yourCheckbox" />
      <label for="group1" class="onlyThese">Publication </label>
    </p>
    <div id="myDiv">the preparation and issuing of a book, journal, or piece of music for public sale.</div>
    <div>
      <p style="float:right">
        <a href="#" rel="modal:close" ; class="onlyThese;"> <b>Apply</b> </a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```